# How do I have a WPF Grid row be of Auto height without exceeding the window height?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

I have a window that contains a `ItemsControl` that can have a variable number of controls inside. In order to account for the case where there are more than will fit in the window height, I wrapped it in a `ScrollViewer`, so that a scrollbar would be shown when the number of items was more than would fit in the height available.

Now, the problem is that sometimes there won't be anything to show in the `ItemsControl` and sometimes there will. Therefore, I set the grid row's height to `Auto` to allow the `ItemsControl` to disappear when empty, or grow when needed. However, this means that the row takes as much height as it needs, even if this exceeds the window height, and the vertical scrollbar is never shown.

Here is some XAML for a sample window that demonstrates the issue...

```
<Window x:Class="DuplicateCustomerCheck.TestScrollViewerWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Test Scroll Viewer Window"
        Height="450"
        Width="200">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBox Name="N"
             TextChanged="TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged"
             Grid.Row="0"
             Margin="3" />

    <Grid Margin="3"
          Grid.Row="1">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <TextBlock Text="Possible duplicate of..."
                 Margin="3" />
      <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                    Grid.Row="1">

        <ItemsControl Name="MatchingNames"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding MatchingNames, Mode=TwoWay}">
          <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
              <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
          </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

          <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <Button Content="{Binding Item}" />
            </DataTemplate>
          </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
      </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2"
               Margin="3"
               Text="Stuff at the bottom" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

For demonstration purposes, here is the button's event handler that allows me to test different numbers of items (note that this is noddy code, so no error-checking etc)...

```
private void TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) {
  MatchingNames.ItemsSource = Enumerable
    .Range(0, int.Parse(N.Text))
    .Select(n1 => new {
      Item = "Button " + n1
    });
}
```

If I change the second grid row's height to `*` then it works fine, but this means that the `ItemsControl` is permanently visible, which I don't want. It should only be shown when there are some items in it.

I tried the `ScrollViewerMaxSizeBehavior` behaviour from [this blog post](https://noamlewis.wordpress.com/2012/01/23/when-to-scroll-the-problem-of-infinite-sized-ui-elements-inside-a-scrollviewer/) ([code here](https://gist.github.com/sinelaw/5495440)), but it didn't make any difference.

Anyone any idea how I can allow the `ItemsControl` to take as much vertical space as it needs, including zero, but not grow taller than can fit in the window?

Comment: How about applying a maxheight to the scrollviewer. Use multibinding and a multiconverter to work out the window.content actualheight and subtract the textblock actualheight.

Comment: it is caused by VerticalScrollbarVisibility property of the Scrollviewer being “Visible”？

Comment: @kennyzx No, it's the same with Auto. I only set it to Visible to see if that helped.

Comment: @Andy I tried setting a MaxHeight, but that didn't stop it exceeding the height of the window. I'm not sure how I'd go about using a multibinding and a multiconverter as you suggested, but it wouldn't be as simple as subtracting the height of the textblock. As I mentioned, this is a sample, in the real window, this part of the XAML is buried deep inside a hierarchy of grids, etc. Would I still be able to use your suggestion? If so, please could you give me some idea how, as I think that's a bit beyond me right now. Thanks

Comment: How about setting ItemsControl Visibility to Collapsed when it is empty?

Comment: @mami Not sure how that would help. The problem is when it's visible, not when it's hidden. I want to restrict the height so it doesn't overflow the window height.

Comment: I meant using the * height that you've said to be working, and hiding the control in case there are no items.

Answer (score 1):

This situation is tricky to be solved with XAML only. I would solve it with some calculations…

```
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MaxHeight="{Binding Row2MaxHeight}"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBox Name="N" TextChanged="TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged" Grid.Row="0" Margin="3" />

    <Grid Margin="3" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MyInnerGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Possible duplicate of..." Margin="3" />
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" MaxHeight="{Binding Row2MaxHeightInner}">
            <ItemsControl Name="MatchingNames" ItemsSource="{Binding MatchingNames, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="{Binding Item}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2"
               Margin="3"
               Text="Stuff at the bottom" />
</Grid>
```

And Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = this;
        SizeChanged += SizeWasChanged;
    }

    private void SizeWasChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e) {
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Row2MaxHeight));
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Row2MaxHeightInner));
    }

    public double Row2MaxHeight => ActualHeight - MyGrid.RowDefinitions[0].ActualHeight - MyGrid.RowDefinitions[2].ActualHeight - 50; //50 or something is around the Size of the title bar of the window
    public double Row2MaxHeightInner => Row2MaxHeight - MyInnerGrid.RowDefinitions[0].ActualHeight - 6; //6 should match the margin of the scrollviewer

    private void TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) {
        MatchingNames.ItemsSource = Enumerable
            .Range(0, int.Parse(N.Text))
            .Select(n1 => new {
                Item = "Button " + n1
            });
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Row2MaxHeight));
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Row2MaxHeightInner));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this question after I had posted [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54301556/373915). At least I *think* we're asking the same thing, although you mention "Therefore, I set the grid row's height to Auto to allow the ItemsControl to disappear when empty, or grow when needed." However, when I tried your sample, even when empty, the `ScrollViewer` is still showing its scrollbars and it's taking up space.

In any case, [mami answered my question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54308213/373915), and although their answer didn't exactly work for me, it along with [Markus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53951023/373915) led me to coming up with [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54314470/373915).

My answer doesn't quite work with your situation though, since mine assumes that the `ItemsControl` is the only thing in the `Grid` row, while you have the "Possible duplicate of..." `TextBlock` in the row too. I tweaked my answer to take the size of the `TextBlock` into account, but it's not as clean as I'd like it to be. As a possible optimization, when computing the total height of the `ItemsControl`'s `Item`s, you could probably exit early once the height gets "big enough" (e.g., larger than the `Window`'s height). That way, if you have thousands of items and only a few dozen would realistically fit on screen, you can just get the height of the few dozen instead of the thousands.

In any case, perhaps it'll give you some ideas :)

XAML:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" MaxHeight="{Binding ItemMaxHeight,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window}}"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox Name="N"
             TextChanged="TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged"
             Grid.Row="0"
             Margin="3" />

        <Grid Margin="3"
          Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Name="tb" Text="Possible duplicate of..."
                 Margin="3" />
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                    Grid.Row="1">

                <ItemsControl Name="MatchingNames"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding MatchingNames, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      SizeChanged="MatchingNames_SizeChanged">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Content="{Binding Item}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2"
               Margin="3"
               Text="Stuff at the bottom" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MatchingNames.ItemsSource = Enumerable
          .Range(0, int.Parse(N.Text))
          .Select(n1 => new
          {
              Item = "Button " + n1
          });
    }

    public double ItemMaxHeight
    {
        get
        {
            if (MatchingNames == null)
                return double.PositiveInfinity;

            double height = 0.0;
            var icg = MatchingNames.ItemContainerGenerator;
            for (int i = 0; i < MatchingNames.Items.Count; i++)
                height += (icg.ContainerFromIndex(i) as FrameworkElement).ActualHeight;

            return height 
                + tb.Margin.Top + tb.ActualHeight + tb.Margin.Bottom
                + 6.0; // 6 should match the margin of the scrollviewer
        }
    }

    private void MatchingNames_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.HeightChanged)
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ItemMaxHeight"));
    }
}
```