# How to have Grid row height take only the space it needs, but also be constrained by available space in its container?

Tags: wpf, layout

I want to have a header, then below that a `ScrollViewer` with an `ItemsControl`, then below that a footer. Something like:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="36"/>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0">Header</TextBlock>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ItemsControl>
                <ItemsControl.Items>
                    <TextBlock>Item 1</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>Item 2</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>Item 3</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>Item 4</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>Item 5</TextBlock>
                </ItemsControl.Items>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2">Footer</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The above is almost what I want, except the middle row is greedy; even if the window is very tall, it takes up as much space as it can, pushing the footer to the bottom of the window.

If I change the middle row's definition to `Height="Auto"`, it takes up exactly the amount of space that it needs, even if that space isn't available, so the `ScrollViewer` never shows the scrollbar, and the footer will get lost off the bottom of the window if the window isn't tall enough.

How do I make it so that if the window is tall enough for everything to fit, the footer is immediately below the `ItemsControl`, but if the window isn't tall enough, the `ScrollViewer` shows a scrollbar and the footer is at the bottom of the window?

I don't necessarily need to do this with a `Grid`, but I didn't find any other `Panel` that would do what I want either. E.g., a `DockPanel` with the header set to `DockPanel.Dock="Top"`, the footer set to `DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"`, and the `ItemsControl` filling the rest behaves exactly the same way.

Some other stuff I've tried:

- Setting `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` on the footer `TextBlock`: no change.
- Making the footer row `Height="*"`: still not what I want; the footer and the `ItemsControl` get the same height, so the footer takes up too much space most of the time, or if you make the window extremely short, it goes off the bottom of the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [mami's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54308213/373915) for the concept of how to do this, and [Markus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53951023/373915) for the idea to bind the Row's `MaxHeight`.

XAML:

```xml
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="36"/>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" MaxHeight="{Binding ItemsMaxHeight,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window}}"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0">Header</TextBlock>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ItemsControl Name="ic" SizeChanged="Ic_SizeChanged">
                <ItemsControl.Items>
                    <TextBlock>Item 1</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>Item 2</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>Item 3</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>Item 4</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>Item 5</TextBlock>
                </ItemsControl.Items>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2">Footer</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel

Class MainWindow
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Public ReadOnly Property ItemsMaxHeight As Double
        Get
            Dim Height = 0.0
            Dim icg = ic.ItemContainerGenerator

            For i = 0 To ic.Items.Count - 1
                Height += DirectCast(icg.ContainerFromIndex(i), FrameworkElement).ActualHeight
            Next

            Return Height + 6.0 ' 6.0 to account for the size of borders? Not sure :(
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Sub Ic_SizeChanged(sender As Object, e As SizeChangedEventArgs)
        If e.HeightChanged Then
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("ItemsMaxHeight"))
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

In this sample XAML, I don't need to increase the MaxHeight by 6, but in my actual app, if I don't add in a little extra, the `ScrollViewer` always shows a scrollbar that can be scrolled a tiny bit. Not sure what causes the discrepancy.

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is a much more elegant way, but at least the below works for me in a similar situation. It is about calculating the real heigth of all items in the ItemsControl and adjusting the Grid's row height if needed.

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True" Loaded="Grid_Loaded">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="36"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" Name="middlerow"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0">Header</TextBlock>
    <ScrollViewer Name="scv" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ItemsControl x:Name="items" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ItemsControl.Items>
                <TextBlock>Item 1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock>Item 2</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock>Item 3</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock>Item 4</TextBlock>
            </ItemsControl.Items>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2">Footer</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

And in code behind:

```
private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        double height = 0;
        foreach (var item in items.Items)
        {
            height += (item as TextBlock).ActualHeight;
        }
        if (height < scv.ActualHeight)
        {
            middlerow.MaxHeight = height;
        }
    }
```

Comment: After posting my question, I looked around some more and found https://stackoverflow.com/a/53951023/373915 . That answer is more complex, and seems very sensitive to being affected by other controls that may be on the window. E.g., it has the magic number "50 or something is around the Size of the title bar of the window". I suspect if another control were to be added above the Grid, that 50 would need to change. However, I did like the use of Binding, so it's updated when needed.

Your solution is much simpler, but it assumes that the items in the `ItemsControl` are all `TextBlock`s.

Comment: In my example, I just filled the `ItemsControl` with `TextBlock`s, but in my actual application, it's data-bound, and uses a `DataTemplate` to generate the actual visual controls. The `Items` collection has my data objects, and there's no `ActualHeight` property. However, I found the `ItemContainerGenerator`, which seems to solve that issue. I've posted an answer that kinda combines your solution and Markus's from the other question.